# White Lines in PDF

Tags: c#, html, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm trying to convert a html table to pdf format. When I view the table in the browsers, no white lines show up but when I export it to pdf there are white lines between every table cell and row. I've tried every css-style to solve it, but none of them work. I'm using Winnovative HTML to PDF converter. Has anyone had this problem or knows how to fix it?

```
.pricelistcontainer table {
width: 100%;
display: table;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-size: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
/*margin-top: 25px;
margin-left: 52px;*/
border: none;
```

}

```
.pricelistcontainer table th {
        border: none;
        background: #000000;
        vertical-align: top;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: arial,sans-serif;
        /*line-height: 1.5;*/
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 4px;
    }



.pricelistcontainer table td {
        /*line-height: 1.5;*/
        border: none !important;
        margin: 0;
        background: #dae2eb;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-family: arial,sans-serif;
        padding-left: 2px;
        color: #000;
        padding-top: 4px;
        padding-right: 4px;
        padding-left: 4px;
    }
```

Comment: please show your html. are you using invisible/white borders or are you using NO borders?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [dopdf](http://www.dopdf.com/download/setup/dopdf_7_0_330.exe) , just install it and press ctrl + p when in the web page. It will show up the print options. Choose the default printer as dopdf and save it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Winnovative uses the Internet Explorer rendering engine, so you might want to check what you see in IE and then adapt your CSS to that.

Alternatively you can use a solution based on webkit like [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) or an API that's offered at [htm2pdf](http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk).